# Baily Borel Compactification: choice of boundary

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups

In Borel/Ji " compactifications of symmetric and locally symmetric spaces " the Baily Borel compactification of a locally symmetric space is defined as
$$\Pi\backslash(X\coprod_{\bf{P}}X_{P,h})$$ where $\Pi$ is an arithmetic group,$X=G/K$ with $G$ the real locus of an algebraic group $\bf{G}$, $K$ a maximal compact subgroup, $\bf{P}$ a maximal parabolic subgroup of $\bf{G}$ and $P$ it's real locus. Moreover, $X_{P,h}$ refers to the hermitian part of the boundary symmetric space associated to $P$.

Now, I have seen people use the hermitian parts $X_{\bf{P},h}$ of the maximal parabolic subgroups $\bf{P}$ as boundary component. Doesn't this make a difference? In general the two boundary spaces $X_P$ and $X_\bf{P}$ are different. Thanks!

Edit: The boundary spaces differ by a Euclidean factor. My guess is that the hermitian part of the boundary spaces are equal.

Comment: Can you clarify the distinction you're making? Is it really between an algebraic-group and real Lie group? An algebraic group isn't really a set of points...

Comment: Thanks, sure: $\bf{P}$ denotes a parabolic subgroup of the linear algebraic group $\bf{G}$, and $P=\bf{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is its real locus. The boundary spaces are obtained via the horospherical decomposition and for general parabolic subgroups $X_{\bf{P}}\neq X_P$. I guess my question is if for maximal parabolic subgroups, at least their hermitian parts are equal.